# Why is this specific C++ implementation of n-body program faster than the Java version?

Tags: java, c++, performance

By looking at the following implementations of the n-body simulation, I have noticed that the C++ version is twice as fast as the Java one. I would like to understand the contributing factors to this performance difference. The benchmarks for the n-body simulation for a wide variety of programming languages can be found here:

http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/nbody.html

Both programs are part of the computer languages benchmark game and can be found here:

http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/

The C++ version is given first below. It was compiled with the following compiler flags: `/usr/bin/g++ -c -pipe -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=native -mfpmath=sse -msse3 --std=c++11 -fopenmp`

```
/* The Computer Language Benchmarks Game
   http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/

   contributed by Mark C. Lewis
   modified slightly by Chad Whipkey
   converted from java to c++,added sse support, by Branimir Maksimovic
   converted from c++ to c, by Alexey Medvedchikov 
   converted from c to c++11, by Walter Landry
   modified by Dmitri Naumov
*/

#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <array>

constexpr double PI(3.141592653589793);
constexpr double SOLAR_MASS ( 4 * PI * PI );
constexpr double DAYS_PER_YEAR(365.24);

struct body {
  double x[3], fill, v[3], mass;
  constexpr body(double x0, double x1, double x2, double v0, double v1, double v2,  double Mass):
    x{x0,x1,x2}, fill(0), v{v0,v1,v2}, mass(Mass) {}
};

class N_Body_System
{
  static std::array<body,5> bodies;

  void offset_momentum()
  {
    unsigned int k;
    for(auto &body: bodies)
      for(k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
        bodies[0].v[k] -= body.v[k] * body.mass / SOLAR_MASS;
  }

public:
  N_Body_System()
  {
    offset_momentum();
  }
  void advance(double dt)
  {
    constexpr unsigned int N = ((bodies.size() - 1) * bodies.size()) / 2;

    static double r[N][4];
    static double mag[N];

    unsigned int i, m;
    __m128d dx[3], dsquared, distance, dmag;

    i=0;
    for(auto bi(bodies.begin()); bi!=bodies.end(); ++bi)
      {
        auto bj(bi);
        for(++bj; bj!=bodies.end(); ++bj, ++i)
          for (m=0; m<3; ++m)
            r[i][m] = bi->x[m] - bj->x[m];
      }

    for (i=0; i<N; i+=2)
      {
        for (m=0; m<3; ++m)
          {
            dx[m] = _mm_loadl_pd(dx[m], &r[i][m]);
            dx[m] = _mm_loadh_pd(dx[m], &r[i+1][m]);
          }

        dsquared = dx[0] * dx[0] + dx[1] * dx[1] + dx[2] * dx[2];
        distance = _mm_cvtps_pd(_mm_rsqrt_ps(_mm_cvtpd_ps(dsquared)));

        for (m=0; m<2; ++m)
          distance = distance * _mm_set1_pd(1.5)
            - ((_mm_set1_pd(0.5) * dsquared) * distance)
            * (distance * distance);

        dmag = _mm_set1_pd(dt) / (dsquared) * distance;
        _mm_store_pd(&mag[i], dmag);
      }

    i=0;
    for(auto bi(bodies.begin()); bi!=bodies.end(); ++bi)
      {
        auto bj(bi);
        for(++bj; bj!=bodies.end(); ++bj, ++i)
          for(m=0; m<3; ++m)
            {
              const double x = r[i][m] * mag[i];
              bi->v[m] -= x * bj->mass;
              bj->v[m] += x * bi->mass;
            }
      }

    for(auto &body: bodies)
      for(m=0; m<3; ++m)
        body.x[m] += dt * body.v[m];
  }

  double energy()
  {
    double e(0.0);
    for(auto bi(bodies.cbegin()); bi!=bodies.cend(); ++bi)
      {
        e += bi->mass * ( bi->v[0] * bi->v[0]
                          + bi->v[1] * bi->v[1]
                          + bi->v[2] * bi->v[2] ) / 2.;

        auto bj(bi);
        for(++bj; bj!=bodies.end(); ++bj)
          {
            double distance = 0;
            for(auto k=0; k<3; ++k)
            {
              const double dx = bi->x[k] - bj->x[k];
              distance += dx * dx;
            }

            e -= (bi->mass * bj->mass) / std::sqrt(distance);
          }
      }
    return e;
  }
};


std::array<body,5> N_Body_System::bodies{{
    /* sun */
    body(0., 0., 0. ,
         0., 0., 0. ,
         SOLAR_MASS),
    /* jupiter */
    body(4.84143144246472090e+00,
         -1.16032004402742839e+00,
         -1.03622044471123109e-01 ,
         1.66007664274403694e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR,
         7.69901118419740425e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR,
         -6.90460016972063023e-05 * DAYS_PER_YEAR ,
         9.54791938424326609e-04 * SOLAR_MASS
         ),
    /* saturn */
    body(8.34336671824457987e+00,
         4.12479856412430479e+00,
         -4.03523417114321381e-01 ,
         -2.76742510726862411e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR,
         4.99852801234917238e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR,
         2.30417297573763929e-05 * DAYS_PER_YEAR ,
         2.85885980666130812e-04 * SOLAR_MASS
         ),
    /* uranus */
    body(1.28943695621391310e+01,
         -1.51111514016986312e+01,
         -2.23307578892655734e-01 ,
         2.96460137564761618e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR,
         2.37847173959480950e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR,
         -2.96589568540237556e-05 * DAYS_PER_YEAR ,
         4.36624404335156298e-05 * SOLAR_MASS
         ),
    /* neptune */
    body(1.53796971148509165e+01,
         -2.59193146099879641e+01,
         1.79258772950371181e-01 ,
         2.68067772490389322e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR,
         1.62824170038242295e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR,
         -9.51592254519715870e-05 * DAYS_PER_YEAR ,
         5.15138902046611451e-05 * SOLAR_MASS
         )
  }};

int main(int , char** argv)
{
  int i, n = atoi(argv[1]);
  N_Body_System system;

  printf("%.9f\n", system.energy());
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    system.advance(0.01);
  printf("%.9f\n", system.energy());

  return 0;
}
```

The Java version is given next:

```
/* The Computer Language Benchmarks Game
   http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/

   contributed by Mark C. Lewis
   modified slightly by Chad Whipkey
   modified slightly by Stefan Feldbinder
   modified slightly by Tagir Valeev
*/

public final class nbody {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        NBodySystem bodies = new NBodySystem();
        System.out.printf("%.9f\n", bodies.energy());
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
           bodies.advance(0.01);
        System.out.printf("%.9f\n", bodies.energy());
    }
}

final class NBodySystem {
   private static final int LENGTH = 5;

   private Body[] bodies;

   public NBodySystem(){
      bodies = new Body[]{
            Body.sun(),
            Body.jupiter(),
            Body.saturn(),
            Body.uranus(),
            Body.neptune()
         };

      double px = 0.0;
      double py = 0.0;
      double pz = 0.0;
      for(int i=0; i < LENGTH; ++i) {
         px += bodies[i].vx * bodies[i].mass;
         py += bodies[i].vy * bodies[i].mass;
         pz += bodies[i].vz * bodies[i].mass;
      }
      bodies[0].offsetMomentum(px,py,pz);
   }

   public void advance(double dt) {
      Body[] b = bodies;
      for(int i=0; i < LENGTH-1; ++i) {
         Body iBody = b[i];
         double iMass = iBody.mass;
         double ix = iBody.x, iy = iBody.y, iz = iBody.z;

         for(int j=i+1; j < LENGTH; ++j) {
            Body jBody = b[j];
            double dx = ix - jBody.x;
            double dy = iy - jBody.y;
            double dz = iz - jBody.z;

            double dSquared = dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz;
            double distance = Math.sqrt(dSquared);
            double mag = dt / (dSquared * distance);

            double jMass = jBody.mass;

            iBody.vx -= dx * jMass * mag;
            iBody.vy -= dy * jMass * mag;
            iBody.vz -= dz * jMass * mag;

            jBody.vx += dx * iMass * mag;
            jBody.vy += dy * iMass * mag;
            jBody.vz += dz * iMass * mag;
         }
      }

      for(int i=0; i < LENGTH; ++i) {
         Body body = b[i];
         body.x += dt * body.vx;
         body.y += dt * body.vy;
         body.z += dt * body.vz;
      }
   }

   public double energy(){
      double dx, dy, dz, distance;
      double e = 0.0;

      for (int i=0; i < bodies.length; ++i) {
         Body iBody = bodies[i];
         e += 0.5 * iBody.mass *
            ( iBody.vx * iBody.vx
                + iBody.vy * iBody.vy
                + iBody.vz * iBody.vz );

         for (int j=i+1; j < bodies.length; ++j) {
            Body jBody = bodies[j];
            dx = iBody.x - jBody.x;
            dy = iBody.y - jBody.y;
            dz = iBody.z - jBody.z;

            distance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);
            e -= (iBody.mass * jBody.mass) / distance;
         }
      }
      return e;
   }
}


final class Body {
   static final double PI = 3.141592653589793;
   static final double SOLAR_MASS = 4 * PI * PI;
   static final double DAYS_PER_YEAR = 365.24;

   public double x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, mass;

   public Body(){}

   static Body jupiter(){
      Body p = new Body();
      p.x = 4.84143144246472090e+00;
      p.y = -1.16032004402742839e+00;
      p.z = -1.03622044471123109e-01;
      p.vx = 1.66007664274403694e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR;
      p.vy = 7.69901118419740425e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR;
      p.vz = -6.90460016972063023e-05 * DAYS_PER_YEAR;
      p.mass = 9.54791938424326609e-04 * SOLAR_MASS;
      return p;
   }

   static Body saturn(){
      Body p = new Body();
      p.x = 8.34336671824457987e+00;
      p.y = 4.12479856412430479e+00;
      p.z = -4.03523417114321381e-01;
      p.vx = -2.76742510726862411e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR;
      p.vy = 4.99852801234917238e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR;
      p.vz = 2.30417297573763929e-05 * DAYS_PER_YEAR;
      p.mass = 2.85885980666130812e-04 * SOLAR_MASS;
      return p;
   }

   static Body uranus(){
      Body p = new Body();
      p.x = 1.28943695621391310e+01;
      p.y = -1.51111514016986312e+01;
      p.z = -2.23307578892655734e-01;
      p.vx = 2.96460137564761618e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR;
      p.vy = 2.37847173959480950e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR;
      p.vz = -2.96589568540237556e-05 * DAYS_PER_YEAR;
      p.mass = 4.36624404335156298e-05 * SOLAR_MASS;
      return p;
   }

   static Body neptune(){
      Body p = new Body();
      p.x = 1.53796971148509165e+01;
      p.y = -2.59193146099879641e+01;
      p.z = 1.79258772950371181e-01;
      p.vx = 2.68067772490389322e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR;
      p.vy = 1.62824170038242295e-03 * DAYS_PER_YEAR;
      p.vz = -9.51592254519715870e-05 * DAYS_PER_YEAR;
      p.mass = 5.15138902046611451e-05 * SOLAR_MASS;
      return p;
   }

   static Body sun(){
      Body p = new Body();
      p.mass = SOLAR_MASS;
      return p;
   }

   Body offsetMomentum(double px, double py, double pz){
      vx = -px / SOLAR_MASS;
      vy = -py / SOLAR_MASS;
      vz = -pz / SOLAR_MASS;
      return this;
   }
}
```

So what are the factors contributing to C++'s performance difference (I can see from the compiler flags that C++ is making use of SSE extensions, including for floating point math, whereas Java is using `java.lang.Math`)? In particular to what correspond the `_mm_loadl_pd`, `_mm_loadh_pd`, `_mm_cvtps_pd`,and `_mm_rsqrt_ps` sets of instructions?

If the performance boost comes from the floating point SSE extensions, would Java also be able in to use such extensions?

Comment: How do you know that the Java program *isn't* using SSE?

Comment: OK then but what factors contribute to the performance difference?

Comment: Well, Java is Java, C++ is C++. I don't want to start a fight but...

Comment: A pretty obvious one there is that `rsqrtps` is used by the fast native implementations, but there is no way to access that instruction from Java. Even if the Java code gets optimized really well by the JIT compiler, that's a transformation that it cannot make because it changes the accuracy significantly.

Comment: So the C++ version is faster but less accurate?

Comment: Well, the guy who made the C++ version decided to make it less accurate in exchange for speed. In Java you don't really have such an option.

Comment: OK but at the end of the simulation, you get the same energy levels as the Java version. So this would mean that the loss of accuracy at the benefit of speed is acceptable in this case

Comment: It still uses a full-accuracy square root for the final energy calculation, apparently the loss of accuracy during this simulation is not a big deal (perhaps it cancels with itself? though in general N-body is chaotic)

Comment: Why are there so many "close" votes on this question? The question is very specific and source code for comparing both implementations is available. Does it not matter to understand why there is such a performance gap?

Comment: It is reasonably specific, but the title "looks annoying" (even to me) and we have to click through some link before it actually becomes a specific question, and then we only have Java and C++ code and we more or less have to guess what the actual code is. If it compared the performance of two assembly listings and left out the whole Java/C++ deal it would probably have gone over better.

Comment: I have rephrased the question to be less "offensive" and provided further details

Comment: This question is far from being too broad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two optimisations at play. The first one is to pack two doubles into a `__m128d` in the two lines

```
dx[m] = _mm_loadl_pd(dx[m], &r[i][m]);
dx[m] = _mm_loadh_pd(dx[m], &r[i+1][m]);
```

In effect, you are, to some extent, parallelising the inner loop by processing the displacements (`r[i]` and `r[i+1]`) **two** at a time, and that's why the outer loop is incremented with `i+=2` rather than `++i`.

The program can actually be made even faster if you pack the values of `r[i][m]` and `r[i+1][m]` at the same time instead of loading them in two separate lines:

```
dx[m] = _mm_set_pd(r[i+1][m], r[i][m]);
```

On my machine, this further shortens the computation time by 4%.

Another optimisation comes from the use of `_mm_rsqrt_ps`, the intrinsic for **single-precision** reciprocal square root. Now I'm not sure if this optimisation is deliberate or if the author was forced to use it, because I couldn't find any intrinsic functions for **double-precision** square root or reciprocal square root for use with `__m128d`. But anyway, single-precision square roots are faster than the double-precision ones.

In order to use single-precision arithmetics, the packed `__m128d` is first converted into four singles (two are converted from the two doubles and the other two are zeroes) by `_mm_cvtpd_ps`. Then `_mm_rsqrt_ps` takes the reciprocal square roots of four singles at the same time. The results of two singles are then converted back to doubles (and the other two are dropped) by `_mm_cvtps_pd`, so you have the following line in the program:

```
_mm_cvtps_pd(_mm_rsqrt_ps(_mm_cvtpd_ps(dsquared)));
```

Unfortunately, single-precision reciprocal square roots are less accurate than the double-precision ones. To correct the errors, we use first-order Taylor expansion that is usually introduced in a introductory calculus course. Let

```
y = f(a) := a^{-1/2}
```

Then, if we perturb `a` by a small `h`, the first-order Taylor expansion about `h=0` is given by

```
f(a+h) ≈ f(a) + hf'(a) = f(a) - (a+h - a)a^{-3/2}/2 = 1.5f(a) - 0.5(a+h)f(a)^3
```

Now, conceptually `dSquared=a+h` and `distance=f(a)` for some `a` close to `h` (or for some `h` close to zero). Therefore, the above Taylor expansion gives

```
f(dSquared) ≈ 1.5 * distance - 0.5 * dSquared * distance * distance * distance
```

However, recall that we have packed two doubles into a `__m128d`. So, we cannot multiply the numbers 1.5 or 0.5 to them. Instead, we pack two doubles of values equal to 1.5 into a `__m128d` and do the similar for 0.5. That's way you get the line below in the program:

```
distance = distance * _mm_set1_pd(1.5)
        - ((_mm_set1_pd(0.5) * dsquared) * distance)
        * (distance * distance);
```

Note that the author uses **reciprocal** square root instead of square root. If square root (without reciprocal) is used instead, one can use the [Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) to correct the numerical errors and the relevant section of the program would become

```
distance = _mm_cvtps_pd(_mm_sqrt_ps(_mm_cvtpd_ps(dsquared)));
// now  dsquared == distance^2 rather than dsquared == 1/distance^2

// Babylonian method: to find the square root x of a number S,
// iterate x_{n+1} = 0.5 * (x_n + S/x_n)
for (m=0; m<2; ++m)
  distance = _mm_set1_pd(0.5) * (distance + dsquared/distance);

// was: dmag = _mm_set1_pd(dt) / dsquared * distance;
dmag = _mm_set1_pd(dt) / (dsquared * distance);
```

However, in the iteration of the Babylonian method, the additional division `dsquared/distance` might make the program slower. Also, it seems that two iterations are not enough to give an accurate result. So, one should use reciprocal square root here, because it results in a faster and more accurate program.

Answer (score 1):

As you seen on a table, languages with automatic memory management alway will be 'slow' also Interpreted languages will play compiled. Java code and C# code it's not an executable file for the specified architecture. Meanwhile, C++ makes executable right for specified architecture.

If you need to be super fast, you should use C++. but this speed usually is not needed.

Choice of language is a very difficult task and we must first of all proceed from the tasks set.

Comment: I agree but whenever I mention this point to a Java/C# developer, they always point out that nowadays Java/C# is just as fast as C++ for numerical computing due to the fact that the JIT has better opportunities in optimizing things.

Comment: And an assembly programmer will tell you assembly is fastest. It's a fact though, that C++ has higher opportunity for specific *optimization* for a given architecture, which will obviously be faster than the general case. I agree with the answer.

Comment: Java/C# nearly as fast as C++ but anyway C++ will be faster because there is no any safety checks, checking memory addressing errors and so on.

Comment: DeiDei:  And an assembly programmer will tell you assembly is fastest.  :) :)

Comment: Well speed is needing in scientific computing and certainly in things such as N-Body problems, unless you enjoy staring at your screen for twice longer :)